# Javascript - Math.random in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, random

Just ran into a something interesting in Javascript while experimenting with generating a random number in the condition (is that what it's called?) of a for loop.

So, if I were to write the code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < Math.floor(Math.random() * 20); j++) {
        count++;
    }
    console.log(count);
}
```

It would return a result like this:

```
9
5
8
3
3
2
6
8
4
4
5
6
3
3
5
3
4
5
3
11
```

But if I were to generate a random number in a variable before the second for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var count = 0;
    var loopEnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
    for (var j = 0; j < loopEnd; j++) {
        count++;
    }
    console.log(count);
}
```

It would return a result like this:

```
11
13
14
2
19
19
17
19
2
18
5
15
18
2
1
19
16
15
13
20
```

What exactly is happening here? It had me confused for a little while. Is the Math.random() inside the for loop generating a new random number after each iteration? Does the loop run the code, iterate, and check the condition, and generate a new random number each time it is checking the condition? Is this what is happening and is this why the numbers in the console are smaller than if I use Math.random() in a variable before the for loop?

Comment: `j < Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)` is run every iteration, and has a different random value each time ... so, of course you will get `false` result much sooner

Comment: Yes, the loop termination condition (including any function calls it makes) is evaluted anew before each iteration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example's inner loop:

```
...
for (var j = 0; j < Math.floor(Math.random() * 20); j++) {
    count++;
}
...
```

the termination condition `j < Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)` is evaluated each iteration of the loop, and so the termination value is changing each iteration with the call to `Math.random()` making it more likely that the loop will terminate earlier.

Comment: Woah. I've been using JavaScript for years and I recently ran into this issue. Great thing to know!

Answer (score 2):

As for the loop terminating earlier on average when the random number is chosen anew every iteration:

Without getting into proper statistical analysis, consider this simple train of thought:

How likely are you to get ten or more iterations?

If you draw just one random number between 1 and 20, you'll get 10 or more about 50% of the time.

If you get ten random numbers you need to have each of them higher than first 1, then 2, then 3 and so on, and the odds are reduced: 95% * 90% * 85% * ... * 50%.

Comment: That's a good point. Interesting to look at it from a statistical point of view. Thanks!